# How do I add a product to an opportunity in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

How do I add a product to an opportunity in a Record Triggered Flow After Save?

In my Element, Create Records, on the Opportunity Object, I believe the field Pricebook2Id has to be relevant, though I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help.

[image: manual method to add Product]

[image: area in Flow to add Product]

Answer (score 0):

So

1. Yes, `Opportunity.Pricebook2Id` is required.  Your flow will need to do a Get Records on `Pricebook2` to locate the ID of the desired pricebook (often, this is the standard Pricebook)
2. When you construct the Opportunity product (`OpportunityLineItem`) you will need a value for the `PricebookEntryId`. This too will need querying for with a Get Records. `PricebookEntry` is a junction record between `PriceBook2` and `Product2`. If you are adding 2+ Opportunity Products, you'll need to query for all of the `PricebookEntry`'s, one for each Opportunity product
3. In the event you are a multi-currency org, you will need to further refine the query for `PricebookEntry` as there is a separate record for each combination of `CurrencyIsoCode : Product2Id : Pricebook2Id`

Comment: Thank you cropredy! I was able to add the Product with the information you gave me: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E02MSH8eA-1PLOLsMd8nWJr2Spme-8--/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: as a service to the community, and if you feel the answer was what you needed, mark it as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark.